# How to prove that exists perfect square between the number $n10^n$ and $(n+1)10^n$?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

I tried with mathematics induction, but I couldn't prove.

Comment: Is the 'between' supposed to be inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: It is inclusive.

Comment: You could try to show that $\sqrt{(n+1)10^n} - \sqrt{n10^n}$ is an increasing sequence, which means that there will always be an integer between the two.

Comment: @Arthut (minor detail) you also need to prove that this value is bigger than 1, which is true for n=2.

Comment: Can I prove with math induction?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: suppose not, then there is a largest $m$ with $m^2\lt n\cdot10^n$ and we also have $(m+1)^2\gt (n+1)\cdot 10^n$

What can you then say about $(m+1)^2-m^2$?

And take it from there to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between consecutive perfect primes $k^2$ and $(k+1)^2$ is $2k+1$.

The difference between $n10^n$ and $(n+1) 10^n$ is $10^n$. Suppose the highest perfect square before the interval is $n10^n$ itself. Then the difference to the next perfect square will be $\sqrt(n10^n)*2+1 = 2\sqrt(n)*\sqrt(10)^n+1$.

This will be smaller than $10^n$ for all $n>=1$. So there must be at least one perfect square in the said interval.